# Is it possible to get Lucene scoring as a number between 0 and 1?

Tags: neo4j, lucene

It seems that the number can be well above or below 1, not in the range of 0-1. Neo4j is using Lucene fulltext search and the scores are not in the range of 0-1. Is this expected in Lucene?

Comment: Related: [Solr: Scores As Percentages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29674709/solr-scores-as-percentages).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the default scoring out of box for Lucene does score between 0 to 1, however once boosting or other custom scoring is involved then the score value can be any positive value that fits in a float.

However, you can easily normalize the scores into the range of 0 to 1 by dividing each hit's score by the max score of any hit in the query as stated by this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5158138/what-does-lucenes-scoredoc-score-mean#answer-5159227).

Comment: RonC, that works to convert it to the range of (0,1] in the example above, however it doesn't really say how relevant or similar the query to the doc. The max float is always 1, even if the top ranked doc is little similar to the the query. I hope a float that really indicates how similar the query to the doc. If the query is 'ab' and the top ranked doc is 'axxxxxyb', they are little 'similar' and the score should be something like 0.02, and instead if the top ranked doc 'abc' or 'cab', then the score could be as high as 0.9. This way the float really make senses of similarity.

Comment: I see.  What you are really asking for is a way to have Lucene score a document on an **absolute** range of 0 to 1 where 0 is "doesn't match at all" and 1 is "perfect match".  I you would need to create your own custom scoring to do that and you'd have to define what "perfect match" evens means.  Say one document contained the search phrase once, and another contained it 3 times and yet another document contained it 5 times.  What score should each get?  Even one containing it 5 times cant be a 1 on an absolute scale since some document could theoretically contain it more times.